# Exlude a row on Import-Csv

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a question concerning `Import-Csv` in PowerShell.
My script reads all *.csv files in my directory and writes it to my MS SQL database. So far so good, but I have a problem in these csv files. They all look the same like this:

```
Header1;Header2;Header3
-----;-----;-----
Data1;Data2;Data3
Data1;Data2;Data3
```

and so on.

My code looks like this:

```
foreach ($File in (Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\data\*.csv')) {
    Import-Csv $File -Delim ';' | ForEach-Object {
        Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database $SQLDatabase -ServerInstance $SQLInstance -Query "insert into dbo.customer_data VALUES ('$($_."Instance Name"............)'
```

Works fine if I remove the line with "---", because PowerShell can't cast this to an integer.

Question: Are there solutions to ignore a row while working with `Import-Csv`? I found out I could skip lines with `Get-Content`, but it seems this can only skip a list of rows and not a specific one. I also thought about exporting csv files without this row with:

```
foreach ($File in (Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\data\*.csv')) {
    Import-Csv $File -Delim ';' |
        where {$_."Instance Name" -ne "-------------"} |
        Export-Csv "C:\data\BaseName.csv" -NoTypeInfo
```

But I think this is not a good solution since files are doubled now and I have no clue about Name placeholders in PowerShell. Or can I actually get the current name of the csv file and overwrite it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot make the cmdlet [Import-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-6) skip specific lines, but you have several other options:

1. Filter out the line *before* converting from CSV:

   ```
   Get-Content $file | where { $_ -notmatch "--" } | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delim ";"
   ```
2. Filter out the item *after* importing the CSV:

   ```
   Import-Csv $file -Delim ";" | where { $_ -notmatch "--" }
   ```
3. Proposed by @AnsgarWiechers (skip the 1st item *after* the import):

   ```
   Import-Csv $file -Delim ";" | select -Skip 1
   ```

Comment: I'd enhance the RegEx to also match possible quoted strings ` $_ -notmatch '"?-{2,}"?'` or ` $_ -notmatch '^["\-;]+$'` in the first variant.

Comment: With this particular data format they could simply skip the first row of the imported data (`Import-Csv | Select -Skip 1`). However, the proper solution to the problem would be to fix the CSV creation.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers One might not always have control over the CSV creation. You're right, in this case `select -skip 1` would work, and I like that solution too. I just wanted to show the parallelism between filtering before & after. There are many other solutions oc.

Comment: I realize that fixing a problem at the source is not always possible, but it would still be the best solution.